# ¿Cómo leer archivos de texto en Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, archivo, kotlin

El contexto es este: Tengo un archivo "informacion.txt", este lo situe en una carpeta nueva (res/raw/informacion.txt); en conde la carpeta nueva es "res".

La información del archivo esta así (Separadas por saltos de linea y entre comillas cada dato):

```
"dato uno"
"dato dos"
"dato tres"
...
"dato n"
```

Entonces recurri a buffererReader para leer los datos que tengo dentro de. Pero no funciona la app, se cierra sola, ya que al "obtener" el dato, quiero ponerlo en un text view y ahi sucede el error. Mi codigo es:

```
 var text:String?  =""

   val filename = "informacion.txt"
    if(filename.toString()!=null && filename.trim() != null){
        var fileInputStream: FileInputStream? = null
        fileInputStream = openFileInput(filename)
        var inputStreamReader: InputStreamReader = InputStreamReader(fileInputStream)
        var bufferedReader: BufferedReader = BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)

        text =  bufferedReader.readLine().toString()

    }

    txtFrase.setText(text)
```

Que esta ocurriendo? o cual es la verdadera forma de leer los datos de mi archivo?

Answer (score 0):

**Abrir archivo desde /raw usando Kotlin.**

Si deseas abrirlo a partir del nombre debes buscar el identificador a partir del nombre, si tu archivo se encuentra en `res/raw/` y se llama `informacion.txt` no es necesario definir la extensión del archivo:

```
val text: String;

val filename = "informacion"
val inputStream = resources.openRawResource( resources.getIdentifier(
    filename,
    "raw", packageName
))
var inputStreamReader: InputStreamReader = InputStreamReader(inputStream)
var bufferedReader: BufferedReader = BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)
text =  bufferedReader.readLine().toString()
```

Comment: Muy bien bro si; lo intente con la segunda, pero aun así no quedo. Así que pensé en lugar de poner todo lo del ´openRawResource( resources.getIdentifier.....´, Solo puse el primero de arriba

Comment: solo es el código de abajo, pero que error o mensaje te muestra?